# Create a project in Soap UI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to know If I can create a new project using Groovy script. What is have tried so far is :

1. Created a sample project manually in Soap UI, added a Test suite, test case and a groovy test step with the following script

   ```
   import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*  
   import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory

   WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject()
   project.setName("Test")
   WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "path pointing to some wsdl", true )[0]
   WsdlOperation operation = iface.getOperationByName( "MyOperation" )
   WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest( "My request" )
   request.setRequestContent( operation.createRequest( true ) )
   ```
2. Run the step

But I am not able to create a project out of it. Can someone help me with what I am missing or going wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do that way while it is easy to create using the tool in a second? What are you trying to achieve? And why is it tagged to java then?

Comment: I want to automate everything straight from creating project to running it. Java tagged by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If I can create a new project using Groovy script*

Yes, definitively.

> *what I am missing*

The newly project should be added to a workspace, at least the workspace of the current project.

Try this:

```
def currentProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

String projectName = "foo"
WsdlProject project = currentProject
                        .getWorkspace()
                        .createProject(projectName, new File(projectName + ".xml"));
```

#### References

- [WsdlProject](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject.html)
- [Workspace](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/workspace/Workspace.html)